# Additional Logging to Std.out Occurs Without Formatting

Tags: python, logging

In Python, with

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename="logname",
                    filemode='a',
                    format='%(asctime)s,%(msecs)03d %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%D %H:%M:%S',
                    level=logging.DEBUG)

logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
logging.info("=================================================")
logging.info("starting execution")
```

I am able to log nicely formatted in the log file:

```
03/30/18 12:52:08,231 root INFO =================================================
03/30/18 12:52:08,232 root INFO starting execution
```

Unfortunately, for the console the formatting is not obeyed:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 173.4674.37)
=================================================
starting execution
```

What do I have to write to make the formatting also possible for the console output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example from the python documentation looked to do the trick https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-multiple-destinations

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename="logname",
                    filemode='a',
                    format='%(asctime)s,%(msecs)03d %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%D %H:%M:%S',
                    level=logging.DEBUG)

console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# set a format which is simpler for console use
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s,%(msecs)03d %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
# tell the handler to use this format
console.setFormatter(formatter)
# add the handler to the root logger
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)

logging.info("=================================================")
logging.info("starting execution")
```

Gives the following console output

```
2018-03-30 19:15:00,940,940 root INFO =================================================
2018-03-30 19:15:07,768,768 root INFO starting execution
```